# Barebones React app instanciates App and calls render twice

Tags: reactjs

Using `npx create-react-app reactTwice`, I've created a barebones React app which does nothing except log certain actions in the console. This shows that the main App class is instantiated twice, and that its `render` method is called twice, even though the values of `this.state` and `this.props` do not change.

I would like to understand why this is happening. Perhaps there is a way to avoid it, perhaps there is a specific reason for this happening that I need to take on board.

You can find the repository for this [here](https://github.com/blackslate/reactTwice/). (Note that this behaviour does not occur when similar code is run on a site like jsFiddle).

Here is the index.js script that launches the App:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

console.log("ReactDOM.render() about to be called")

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

console.log("ReactDOM.render() was called")
```

Here is the script that generates the `App` class:

```
import React from 'react';

let instance = 0

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.startTime = + new Date()
    this.instance = ++instance
    this.state = {}
    this.imageError = this.imageError.bind(this)

    console.log("App constructor (", this.instance, ")", this.getTime())
  }


  getTime() {
    return + new Date() - this.startTime 
  }


  runTimeOutMethod() {
    console.log("runTimeOutMethod started (", this.instance, ")", this.getTime())
    this.setState({ time: true })
    console.log("runTimeOutMethod complete (", this.instance, ")",  this.getTime())
  }


  imageError(event) {
    console.log("DOM element added (", this.instance, ")", this.getTime())
  }


  render() {
    console.log(
      "render called (", this.instance, ")"
    ,  this.getTime()
    , this.state
    , this.props
    )

    return (
      <div className="App">
       <img src="" alt="no src" onError={this.imageError} />
      </div>
    );
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount started (", this.instance, ")", this.getTime())
    this.setState({ mounted: true })
    setTimeout(this.runTimeOutMethod.bind(this), 0)
    console.log("componentDidMount complete (", this.instance, ")", this.getTime())
  }
}
```

Here is sample output in the Console. I've added formatting for readability.

```
index.js: 5 ReactDOM.render() about to be called

App.js:14 App constructor ( 1 ) 0
App.js:14 App constructor ( 2 ) 0

App.js:36 render called ( 2 ) 1 {} {}
App.js:36 render called ( 2 ) 2 {} {}

App.js:52 componentDidMount started ( 2 ) 24
App.js:55 componentDidMount complete ( 2 ) 26
App.js:36 render called ( 2 ) 29 {mounted: true} {}
App.js:36 render called ( 2 ) 29 {mounted: true} {}

index.js:14 ReactDOM.render() was called

App.js:31 DOM element added ( 2 ) 46

App.js:24 runTimeOutMethod started ( 2 ) 47
App.js:36 render called ( 2 ) 48 {mounted: true, time: true} {}
App.js:36 render called ( 2 ) 48 {mounted: true, time: true} {}
App.js:26 runTimeOutMethod complete ( 2 ) 49
```

Comment: You do set the state in componentDidMount, which should trigger a rerender.

Comment: @A.Larsson True. But that does not explain anything. Setting the state in `componentDidMount` causes the component to render again after the `componentDidMount` method completes, as I would expect. But (a) the class is instantiated twice and (b) the component renders twice at every step: twice after instantiation, twice after `componentDidMount` and twice in the custom `runTimeOutMethod`. Neither state nor props changes at all before the second of these renders.

Answer (score 0):

All the symptoms of this issue are caused by the use of `<React.StrictMode>` in the `index.js` file, and this is the [expected behaviour](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12856). Dan Abramov wrote:

> The whole purpose of StrictMode is to find cases where the user-written functions that are supposed to be pure are, in fact, not pure... [This is n]ot an error, but a mutation or a side effect. Yes, [calling twice] is arbitrary, but we've found it works really well in practice.

These side-effects stop occurring if you alter `index.js` so that it reads:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <App />
  </>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In any case, the double calls to the constructor and to `render` will not be made in production mode.